# Mocking new Class(mockObject.getid)

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I need to mock a new class call then use that class mock to mock a method call

`

```
Static List<someObject> getObject(mockFoo){
ObjectManager objManager = new ObjectManager(mockFoo.getManager())
return objManager.SomeMethod(mockFoo.getID(), bar.getType.TYPE);
}
```

`

SomeMethod hits the DataBase and I need to avoid this and return mocked test data

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest example would be

```
@Test
void newTest(){
    SomeClass someClass = mock(SomeClass.class);
    Mockito.when(recipient.getName()).thenReturn("SomeMockedName");
    System.out.println(recipient.getName());
}
```

This mocks a class, mocks a method and shows that it works.

If you are using spring you could try different approaches by using

```
@Mock
SomeRepository someRepository

@InjectMocks
SomeService someService
```

but the simple example above should also work there